# get selected category name on category page wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to fetch the particular category name on the category page. For eg:- there are 5 categories.. **a,b,c,d,e**... so if i am viewing the category a then page should display "**i am *a* category**"... similarly if I click on b category link, the page should display "**I am category *b***".....

In wordpress, I am not able to get the selected category name on the category page.... i.e  if i have clicked on category name "face", i want to display the name face on the page and if I have clicked on the category name "hand", I want to display the name "hand" on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your theme directory, you should have a template `category.php`. In this template, you can display the name of the current category with the following [Template Tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags):

```
 <?php single_cat_title(); ?>
```